# Unable to access global variables via Runnable in class

Tags: java, class, runnable

Good Day,

I have a class called FunctionHandler, that contains a method called evaluate like this:

```
class FunctionHandler{
 Object globalVar;

 public void Evaluate(){
      ThreadPool pool;

      Runnable task = new Runnable(){
          public void run() {  aWorkerTask(globalVar); }
      }


      pool.start(task);
      pool.stop();
 }

 public void aWorkerTask(Object object){//worker stuff}
}
```

The problem is, my Runnable object can't seem to access globalVar! It seems to be it's own object somehow that can't reference what is inside it's class. Is there anyway around it?

The problem is that this code inherently doesnt work. Runnable cannot access globaVar. I need aWorkerTask to be wrapped in a Runnable and it needs access to globalVar

Comment: You need some semicolons.

Comment: It was more a general example to show the structure

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? What is the exact code you're running? This example doesn't really help us at all.

Comment: The problem is that this code inherently doesnt work. Runnable cannot access globaVar. I need aWorkerTask to be wrapped in a Runnable and it needs access to globalVar

Comment: The idea is the multiple runnables with different globalVars will be fed into a thread pool. Once they are all done, it joins/stops at the end and the function evaluate is done

Comment: There are still syntax errors with the code in the OP after your edit. Can you post the actual code (trimmed down) and/or the actual error message?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best implementation, but what I did was to create a class that implements Runnable as such:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private FunctionHandler functionHandler; //Global Reference - Only reading from it
            private Object globalVar;

        public MyRunnable(FunctionsHandler functionsHandler,Object globalVar) {
            this.functionsHandler = functionsHandler;
            this.globalVar = globalVar;
        }

        public void run(){
              functionHandler.aWorkerTask(globalVar)
        }
}
```

And pass in the main object functionHandler, which contains the function I need to make as a Runnable. 
I then create a runnable as such:

```
MyRunnable taskProcessor = new MyRunnable(this,variableName,functionValues,jobNum.toString());
threadPool.runTask(taskProcessor);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Runnable object is indeed its own object.  Your options are to  set it via a mutator or declare globalVar as final.  Here's the mutator solution, in case you don't want globalVar to be final:

```
public void startRun() {
    Object globalVar = new Object();
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        Object localVar;
        public Runnable prepare(Object param) {
            localVar = param;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Do your stuff */
        }
    }.prepare(globalVar);
}
```

Note that if you do this and you want globalVar to be modifiable both inside and outside the thread, you'll need to wrap it in a suitable dereferencing object.

Comment: Fields don't need to be final to be accessed by an anonymous/local class. I suspect there is something fundamentally different with the OP's actual code such as that `globalVar` actually is a local variable or it is an instance variable and `Evaluate` is a static method.

Comment: Member variables don't, but local variables do.  If the OP can't access globalVar, the most likely reason is because he's using a local variable.

Comment: At this point you probably want to create a new class since your anonymous inner class is getting a bit on the long side.

Comment: Yep.  Anonymous classes are always too long IMO, they just add garbage boilerplate in the middle of otherwise fluid code; the OP's solution was to write his own class, and that's a good way of doing it.  Sometimes, especially for temporary or "debug" code, this way is handy, and many people don't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want runnables to be able to access class variables, they have to be static; just change your code to:

```
 static Object globalVar;
```